# How to force Microsoft Word to use styles etc when pasting an HTML Fragment containing H! headers

Tags: html, ms-word, tags, styles

I have an application which creates an HTML Fragment containing H1, H2 tags plus a number of HTML tables. What I have noticed is that if I paste this fragment into a Word document that does not already use the Heading Styles, the H1 tags are converted into 'Normal' text. If the document already uses Heading styles, Word takes notice of the H1, H2 tags. e.g., H1 elements use the Heading 1 style etc.

Anyone know why this should be and how I can force Word to take account of the Heading Tags?

Many thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.